# How to find a 2D array in a 2D array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

There is a `numpy` `array()` with `m x n` size, and I want to get indexes that match a particular pattern.

Since the `map` would be bigger than the example below, I guess solving with loop is not efficient.

[image]

In this example, I want to get the following as result:

```py
[
   [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)],
   [(1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6)]
]
```

Is there any tool to do this easily?

Comment: Please, avoid [posting images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). It is a better practice to transcribe them instead. Also, bear in mind that `map` is a standard Python function, so when you use that name as a variable, you are overwriting it.

Comment: @accdias Thanks for your advice and assistance. I'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 2):

You can efficiently solve this problem using a **convolution** where the filter is:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

This can be done efficiently with [`scipy.signal.convolve2d`](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html#scipy.signal.convolve2d).

The resulting array can then be filtered by looking for values greater than the sum of the previous filter (ie. 5). This can be done with `np.where(result >= 5)`.

Note that for big pattern, you can use an FFT-based convolution.

To summarize, you can do:

```py
np.where(scipy.signal.convolve2d(m, np.flip(f), mode='valid') >= 5)
```